# magmi import not found

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

I'm trying to use the magmi extension to import bulk categories/products, but when I try to import my .csv file I get this error:

```
---- TRACE : 1 -----
---- DATE : 2015-04-24 11:24:36 ------
************************************
not found
*************************************
/plugins/base/datasources/csv/magmi_csvdatasource.php:121 - Magmi_CSVReader->checkCSV
----------------------------------------
```

Is this a known issue? and did someone find a fix yet?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem. Turns out that "Configurable Item processor v1.3.7a" was checked and by unchecking it, the problem went away. But I do need this option so after a bit of troubleshooting, it was a mistake in my column name. I was trying to use "drop-down" but it should have been "drop_down".

This mysterious error probably means you have a syntax error in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I like the MAGMI importer. It is a very versatile and powerful tool.

I think the error you are getting is due to this line of code:

```
file: magmi/inc/magmi_csvreader.php
class: Magmi_CSVReader
function: checkCSV

throw new Magmi_CSVException("{$this->_filename} not found");
```

And the error message you get suggests the filename is an empty string so you just see 'not found'.

Double check the way you are setting the CSV filename and saving the MAGMI config. For example, it is possible that the config file cannot be saved due to permission restrictions. After you save the MAGMI config you should be able to see the filename and path to your CSV file in the MAGMI configuration file:

```
file:magmi/conf/Magmi_CSVDataSource.conf
[Magmi_CSVDataSource]
CSV:importmode = "local"
CSV:basedir = "var/import"
CSV:filename = "...SOME_PATH.../var/import/your-upload-file.csv"
```

And also check that the CSV file exists and is readable.

If you can't spot the problem please give more details about how your are running MAGMI and where you are storing the CSV file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. it seemed the error was caused by one of the product plugins. these three to limit it down Grouped Item processor v1.4.1 info
name:Grouped Item processor
version:1.4.1
author:Alpine Consulting, Inc & Dweeves
url:Wiki entry
This plugins handles grouped item import
documentation
 Bundle Item processor v1.1 info
name:Bundle Item processor
version:1.1
author:Björn Tantau,dweeves,igi8819
url:Wiki entry
This plugins handles bundle item import
documentation
 Configurable Item processor v1.3.7a

Comment: turned those to off and it started working. I will need those in the future though so i'm gonna debug it then and find the error.